# I want return type pointer but i want my function to return pointer of derive class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
Dragon* Dragon::spawn() {
    int x = rand() % 5;
    int y;
    if (!if_locked(x)) //is a function to see if that id is unlocked because i want some dragon to be generated only if you have certain xp so it will call func again until unlocked id is generated
        spawn();
    else
        y = unlocking(m); // Y is generated form 1-5, I have assigned Id to each derive class whosoever id matches Y that pointer will be returned

    if (y == 1) {
        GroundDragon* pt;
        return pt;
        }

    if (y == 2) {
        WaterDragon* st;
        return st;
    }
    if (y == 3) {
        IceDragon*bt;
        return bt;
    }
    if (y == 4) {
        FireDragon* ct;
        return ct;
    }
    if (y == 5) {
        DarkDragon* dark;
        return dark;
    }
}
```

As you can see im making syntax mistakes i hope someone can guide me

The return type of function is base class and all the classes in if statement are derive class

so i can later use this function

```
 template<class T>
 void spawner(T*) {// I will spawn() fucntion as perimeter at time of call 
   T = new T;
 }
```

Forgive me if im repaeting question the last time i post it didnt get attention i was expecting so i modifed my code a bit hopeful it is clear now`

```
int Dragon::unlocking(Mage m) {


if (m.getxp() <= 50 and m.getxp() <= 100) {
    unlock[0] = 1;
    cout << "Congratulation GroundDragon unlocked " << endl;
    return 1;
}

if (m.getxp() > 100 and m.getxp() < 150) {
    unlock[1] = 1;
    cout << "Congratulation WaterDragon unlocked " << endl;
    return 2;
}
if (m.getxp() > 150 and m.getxp() < 175) {
    unlock[2] = 1;
    cout << "Congratulation IceDragon unlocked " << endl;
    return 3;
}

if (m.getxp() > 175 and m.getxp() < 500) {
    unlock[3] = 1;
    cout << "Congratulation FireDragon unlocked " << endl;
    return 4;
}

if (m.getxp() > 500) {
    unlock[4] = 1;
    cout << "Congratulation DarkDragon unlocked " << endl;
    return 5;
}
```

}

```
bool Dragon::if_locked(int x) {
if (unlock[x] == 1) {
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
```

}

[image]
*Im not comfortable with smartpointer(i have never used them before but i would love to use them if you show me how to call it main *
I used raw pointer but it is still showing me errors please help mw

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you need and what is your problem?

Comment: I want this function to return pointers of derive classes after condition becomes true

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct. You can't return the derived type because then exactly _which_ derived type would you return?

Comment: Why does `spawn()` not `new` the returned derived class instance, thereby having no need of `spawner()`?

Comment: @acraig5075 Returning a result of `new` as a raw pointer is heavily discouraged nowadays.

Comment: Your edit says that you are now using smart pointers, yet nothing in your code uses those. As for your errors, it does not know certain terms, like `fire` or `GroundDragon`. Where did you define those? We need that part of the code. Maybe start by creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in general, us asking for more of your code will otherwise become tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is sound, it's just the execution that failed.

If you want to have a factory function that will return different objects that will then behave polymorphically, this is perfectly fine, with one important thing - you need to return actual objects.

Your factory function has a return type of `Dragon*`. This means that whatever value you return, it will be a pointer pointing to (some sort of a) `Dragon`. However, the value of that pointer can point to an object that is actually an instace of `FireDragon`, `IceDragon` etc. When you create an instance of such an object, the pointer to such instance can then get converted to the appropriate return type and returned.

In your case though, while you're creating temporary objects of type pointer-to-some-sort-of-dragon, you're not actually filling them with instances. They all are created with an *unspecified* value, and that value is then converted to an unspecified value of type `Dragon*`, with no way to extract the information which type it was converted from.

So, in order to make it work in a usual fashion, we just need to create a new instance of appropriate type and return it. We don't ever want to return raw pointers from functions when transferring ownership, so `std::unique_ptr` is a much better alternative:

```
std::unique_ptr<Dragon> Dragon::spawn() {
    int x = rand() % 5;

    /* note - this bit of code doesn't make any sense whatsoever
    int y;
    if (!if_locked(x)) //is a different function
        spawn();
    else
        y = unlocking(m); //is also a different function
    */

    // note that `rand() % 5` will produce values 0 through 4.
    switch(x) {
        case 0: return std::make_unique<GroundDragon>();
        case 1: return std::make_unique<WaterDragon>();
        case 2: return std::make_unique<IceDragon>();
        case 3: return std::make_unique<FireDragon>();
        case 4: return std::make_unique<DarkDragon>();
    }
}
```

Now you don't need the `spawner` function at all; you can directly use the returned value.

Comment: The part you commented out is about checking whether spawning a certain type of dragon is currently allowed, if I am correct. His code doesn't do that correctly, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first important lesson to give is about initializing pointers.

The line
`GroundDragon* pt;`
declares that there is a pointer to a `GroundDragon` object, so far so good.   However, this does *not* create an object.
As an analogy: you created a direction sign that is able to point into the direction of a village, but you do not build an actual village for it to point towards. And right now, it just points into some random direction.
Being uninitialized, `pt` contains a random value, not the address of an existing object of type `GroundDragon`. Doing anything with it will most likely result in bad things (it is undefined behaviour in particular).
In order to initialize it, you would write it like
`GroundDragon* pt = new GroundDragon;`
This creates an objects of type `GroundDragon` on the heap and assigns it's address to `pt`.
Also note that every `new` needs a `delete` to keep the memory clean, just to mention this preemptively.

This is very essential knowledge - make sure to understand this.

I wanted to write this in order to show you how to work with raw pointers, as an addition to the answer of Bartek Banachewicz, who did not show the way to initialize raw pointers. What he then does, using smart pointers, is clearly a way better approach than using raw pointers, though. However, I'd say that it is quite important that you are also able to work with raw pointers. Make sure to be able to do both in the long run, and use smart pointers whenever you can.

Edit: Now for the other part of your code,

```
int x = rand() % 5;
int y;
if (!if_locked(x)) //is a function to see if that id is unlocked because i want some dragon to be generated only if you have certain xp so it will call func again until unlocked id is generated
    spawn();
else
    y = unlocking(m);
```

First of all, please be aware that calling `spawn();` ignores the return value. Which means, it has no effect at all. What you probably wanted to write is `return spawn();`.
Second, `if(!if_locked(x))` seems to me to be the contrary of what it should be. "if not locked" means "if unlocked", and in that case, it should not try it again but instead proceed, right?
And, is the `Mage m` that you give to `unlocking` a member of `Dragon`? Sounds like it rather should be a pointer, if you don't especially want a relationship like `Dragon` owns `Mage`.

In any case, I would keep `unlocking` out of `spawn`. A method like `spawn` says that it is good for spawning. Especially printing that something is unlocked is not something I would intuitively understand a part of the spawning process. Also, I would name it differently, as "unlocking" is a status rather than a command. Go like `check_for_new_unlocks` or something like that, which sounds like a command. And do it separately from `spawn`.

Also, note that you check for narrow experience intervals - are you sure that it can't happen that an interval is never triggered, as the character might advance over the interval with never calling the method in between?

Furthermore, I'd call the array that says if something is unlocked differently. "unlock" sounds like a command. How about "available"?

Also, I find the recursive call of `spawn` to be less readable as trying out other values for `x`, but that is opinion. I'd go like

```
int x = rand() % 5;
while(not available[x])
{
    x = rand() % 5;
}
```

Maybe this can be done more clever, though, based on the actual mechanics. You could create the random variable like `int x = rand() % total_available();` for instance.

Note that a lot of this is somewhat opinion based. In this regard, I want to point you towards [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - as soon as your code works correctly, you might want to post it there for people to help you improve it in several different regards.